# proof of a^2 + ab + b^2 >0; a,b, both are not zero, both are real

Tags: analysis

Show that for any reals a,b, both of which are not zero, it holds true that a^2 + ab + b^2 >0

Comment: "Hint": $$a^2+ab+b^2=\dfrac{(a+b)^2+a^2+b^2}{2}.$$

Comment: If an answer satisfies you, could you mark it as such.

Answer (score 2):

$$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$
So you want to show
$$(a+b)^2-ab>0$$
Or
$$(a+b)^2>ab$$
If $a$ and $b$ are not of the same sign you are done. If not, consider the rectangle of sides $a$ and $b$ and see that it fits inside the square of side $a+b$.

Answer (score 1):

$$a^2+ab+b^2=\dfrac{(2a+b)^2+(\sqrt3b)^2}4\ge\dfrac{(\sqrt3b)^2}4$$